# fail to login via facebook (InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 191) in laravel 5.1 socialite

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

i'm trying to make facebook login system on my site.
here's my routes for facebook authorization

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

here are my methods in authController

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    //some code....
}
```

so when i click on link(which is redirect to FB) i got this error

```
InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 191:
```

in my services.php file

```
 'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '1730035173900238',
    'client_secret' => 'cdda4132a5b67249a08b1d777f7a69ad',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/{$lang}/auth/facebook/callback',
]
```

that $lang is language prefix for all routes.
i also added in my session.php

```
'domain' => "localhost"
```

in my app on facebook i have

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

in Site URL field

Comment: You deleted your quetion `The parameter app_id is required in laravel 5.1 socialite` (I found with [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:--feK-b8QI4J:stackoverflow.com/questions/35379150/the-parameter-app-id-is-required-in-laravel-5-1-socialite+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr)) but I have the same issue, how have you solve it ?

Comment: that means, url in your code doesnt match the url that you have in your facebook app (or any other social network). i can send you some printscreens if you want(it will be easier to understand with them), just tell me your mail

Comment: I have created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35536548/3452348). Everything is ok now

Comment: seems like you have a different problem. anyway, i show you all steps that i did

Answer (score 1):

put this code in the top of your class

```
    use Auth;
```

in you authController
It solve my problem

And make sure your domain setting in config/session.php

```
   'domain' => null,
```

hope this will help you...

Cheers

Hendra