# Unable to use Laravel / Socialite with Lumen

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth, lumen

I try to use the package [Laravel\Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) in my system in [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1) (5.1)

I added this in the `config\services.php` file :

```
<?php
//Socialite
'facebook' => [
    'client_id'     => '##################',
    'client_secret' => '##################',
    'redirect'      => 'http://local.dev/admin/facebook/callback',
],
```

In `bootstrap\app.php` file :

```
class_alias(Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class, 'Socialite');
$app->register(Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class);
```

Then I created a controller for the facebook authentication :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Facebook;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;

class FacebookController extends Controller
{
  public function redirectToProviderAdmin()
  {
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes(['manage_pages', 'publish_actions'])->redirect();
  }

  public function handleProviderCallbackAdmin()
  {
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
  }
}
```

And in the `routes.php` :

```
$app->get('/admin/facebook/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Facebook\FacebookController@redirectToProviderAdmin');
$app->get('/admin/facebook/callback', 'App\Http\Controllers\Facebook\FacebookController@handleProviderCallbackAdmin');
```

I just followed the documentation, changing according to my needs. When I go to page `http://local.dev/admin/facebook/login`, I get the following error :

> Non-static method Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory::driver() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Indeed, according to the code, [driver function](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Contracts/Factory.php) must be instanciate.

**EDIT** : And if I try to instanciate this class, I get the following error :

> Cannot instantiate interface Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory

How do you make this module to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how that works in my case

in services.php file

```
 'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '***************',
    'client_secret' => '***************',
    'redirect' => ""
],
```

i left redirect empty cause my site is multilingual (so, it fills in a bit later with sessions). if you use only one language, put there your callback absolute path. for example

```
"http://example.com:8000/my-callback/";
```

also check your config/app.php. in providers array

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

in aliases array

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

my routes look like this

```
Route::get('facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

here's auth controllers methods. put in top

```
use Socialite;
 //იობანი როტ
 public function redirectToProvider(Request $request)
{
    return Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

 public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
  {
    //here you hadle input user data
    $user = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();

  }
```

my facebook app
[image: fb_settings]

giga.com:8000 is my localhost (so its the same localhost:8000)

[image: fb_settings2]

[image: fb_settings3]

as you can see in Valid OAuth redirect URI, you should put there your callback. in my case i use three urls cause i have three languages. in your case it should be just

```
http://your-domain-name.com:8000/callback
```

if you work on localhost, you should name your domain in config/services.php
mine look like this

```
'domain' => "your-domain.com",
```

after everything run these commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

restart your server, clear your browser cookies. hope it helps

Comment: Wow, very good answer. Thanks. SO users, **read my answer too**