# Any examples of Laravel Socialite used in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, expo, laravel-socialite

i want to use `laravel-socialite` with  react native , my question is how to redirect from browser of phone to application (react native) with token from laravel ?
any suggestion?

Comment: I think you should use laravel api. Maybe think can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966605/using-laravel-socialite-with-an-api

Comment: @KhayankhyarvaaTurmandakh thanks my problem is how to redirect from browser of phone to my app

Comment: Few years ago I tried this flow. I remember that first step is your app support custom url schema. second step is when call app from browser is require user click action on the web site

Comment: @KhayankhyarvaaTurmandakh any more detail ?