# Social Login with Angular 5 and Lumen 5.6

Tags: laravel, angular5, social-authentication, lumen-5.5

I am trying to implement social login with angular 5 as my front-end and lumen 5.6 as my backend.

I am using JWT Authentication system with Lumen. 
So, I am confused here how I should implement social login system in this situation.

Through my research I have come to these libraries which can do that work, but I am not sure how the process is handled from the front-end (angular) to back-end (lumen).

```
For Angular 5 -
angularx-social-login OR Satellizer
For Lumen -
laravel/socialite
```

But as I have not found any documentation on Satellizer working with Angular 5, so I choosed to use other one.

I have read this article, but still the process from front-end to back-end is not clear to me.
https://medium.com/@barryvdh/oauth-in-javascript-apps-with-angular-and-lumen-using-satellizer-and-laravel-socialite-bb05661c0d5c

Any explanatory help ?

Comment: Documentation is super clean enough to understand. In Angular You can inject to headers:  `Authorization: Bearer {jwt here}` before doing request to backend api. And backend just will take that http header and just explode that header attribute and get that jwt token to resolve data encoded inside of jwt.

Comment: The way i set this up was have the front end sign in and get the token and information like email and name and then send that over to the back end and then verify the token so with google it was using the graph to verify it was valid and get the information back then from there check if they where a user or not and then ethier create them an account or sign them in, You can sign them in with just an email on Lumen. I can post example as an answer if you would like

Comment: @SCRATK Yes, do that, let me understand the process through your example, my main confusion is should I implement satellizer with angular 5 to process all the social login, and then send the email or info of the user to the lumen api for logging in and return a token through my JWT authentication to work further ? , is this approach is correct ?

Comment: It is the approach I have used I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

So the way I used social login with Angular 5 is with a package called

`"angular5-social-login": "^1.0.9",`

So add that to your `package.json` file.

Import it in `app.module.ts`

`import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig, GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider } from 'angular5-social-login';`

Set up a function in `app.module.ts`

```
export function getAuthServiceConfigs() {
  const config = new AuthServiceConfig(
      [
        {
          id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          provider: new FacebookLoginProvider('') // Left as i dont use it
        },
        {
          id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          provider: new GoogleLoginProvider('YOUR-API-TOKEN.apps.googleusercontent.com')
        },
      ]
  );
  return config;
}
```

Add it to your Imports in `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
    SocialLoginModule, // One we need to add
  ],
```

Then at the add it to your providers in `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
    YourServices,
    ...
    ApiAuthService,
    {
        provide: AuthServiceConfig,
        useFactory: getAuthServiceConfigs
    },
    LoggedInGuard,
],
```

As you can see i have a `LoggedInGuard` and a `ApiAuthService` these are these with the auth and checking your logged in.

So That's the package installed and set up...

Now inside of `api-auth.service.ts` add this function

```
socialSignIn(userData) {
    const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('email', userData.email);
      formData.append('name', userData.name);
      formData.append('provider', userData.provider);
      formData.append('id', userData.id);
      formData.append('idToken', userData.idToken);
      formData.append('token', userData.token);
      formData.append('image', userData.image);
    return this._http.post(
      environment.apiUrl + '/auth/social-signin/',
      formData,
      {
        headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userData.idToken
        })
      }
    );
  }
```

Now in your sign in component add this to the HTML

```
<div (click)="socialSignIn('google')" class="c2a_btn large google">
    Log in with google 
</div>
```

In your sign in component .ts file add this function

```
import { AuthService, FacebookLoginProvider, GoogleLoginProvider, LinkedinLoginProvider } from 'angular5-social-login';
import { ApiAuthService } from '../../../../services/api-auth.service';
import { TokenService } from '../../../../services/token.service';


public socialSignIn(socialPlatform: string) {
    this.loading = true;
    let socialPlatformProvider;
    if (socialPlatform === 'facebook') {
      socialPlatformProvider = FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
    } else if (socialPlatform === 'google') {
      socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
    } else if (socialPlatform === 'linkedin') {
      socialPlatformProvider = LinkedinLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
      (userData) => {
        this._apiAuthService.socialSignIn(userData)
        .map( data => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .subscribe(
          token => {
            this._tokenService.setAccessToken(token.access_token);
          },
          error => {
            this.invalidLogin = true;
            this.loading = false;
          },
          () => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.closeSignIn.emit('out');
            // this._router.navigate(['/profile']);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

This is just the front end now for the back end. I'm using Laravel 5.6

But I made a function like this

```
public function socialSignIn(Request $request, Response $response) {

        $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $provider = $request->input('provider');

        if ($provider == 'google') {
            $id_token = $request->header('Authorization');
            $id_token = str_replace("Bearer ","",$id_token);

            $CLIENT_ID = Config::get('google.client_id');

            $email = $request->input('email');
            $names = $request->input('name');
            $name = explode(' ', $names);

            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setDeveloperKey($CLIENT_ID);
            $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
            if ($payload) {
                if (User::where('email', '=', $email)->exists()) {

                    $user = User::Where('email', '=', $email)->first();
                    if(!Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)){
                        return response()->json([
                            'failed'
                        ], 403);
                    }

                    $updateLastLoginDate = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)-first();
                    $updateLastLoginDate->last_login_date = $date;
                    $updateLastLoginDate->save();

                    $activeAccount = Auth::user();
                    $activeAccount->active = '1';
                    $activeAccount->save();

                } else {

                    $recordUser = New User;
                    $recordUser->email = $request->input('email');
                    $recordUser->last_login_date = $date;
                    $recordUser->save();

                    $recordLinkedSocialAcounts = new LSA;
                    $recordLinkedSocialAcounts->user_id = $recordUser->id;
                    $recordLinkedSocialAcounts->provider_name = $provider;
                    $recordLinkedSocialAcounts->provider_id = $request->input('id');
                    $recordLinkedSocialAcounts->save();

                    $recordUserInformation = new UPI;
                    $recordUserInformation->user_id = $recordUser->id;
                    $recordUserInformation->first_name = $name[0];
                    $recordUserInformation->last_name = $name[1];
                    $recordUserInformation->last_login_date = $date;
                    $recordUserInformation->image = $request->input('image');
                    $recordUserInformation->save();

                    if(!Auth::loginUsingId($recordUser->id)){
                        return response()->json([
                            'failed'
                        ], 403);
                    }
                }

                return response()->json([
                    'access_token' => Auth::user()->createToken('access_token')->accessToken,
                    'role_id' => Auth::user()->role_id
                ], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'failed'
                ], 403);
            }
        }
    }
```

I will most probably make a video on this soon. Any questions just ask

Comment: What did you do for lumen you haven't explained it's use here

Comment: @BlackMamba Check out this for setting up Socialite with Lumen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536548/unable-to-use-laravel-socialite-with-lumen

Comment: Ohh ok but I was waiting for your video ;)

Comment: @BlackMamba I will try and get it sorted I have a video for Laravel 5 just not had time recently